# jquery calculates font-size

Tags: jquery, css

I want to calculate the max size of allowed text width. I have the following function:

```
function MyFitText(width, text) {
    var ourText = $('span').css('font-weight', 'bold').val(text);
    var fontSize = 20;
    ourText.css('font-size', fontSize);
    do {
        fontSize = fontSize - 1;
        textWidth = ourText.width();
        ourText.css('font-size', fontSize);
    } while ((textWidth > width) && fontSize > 1);

    return fontSize;
}
```

and call this:

```
var fontSize = MyFitText(65, '195 reviews']);
```

But really it retuns 1, but size at least 6 is allowed for that width. Why?

Comment: A numeric font-size without a unit is invalid unless it is zero. If you make the browser enter the realm of tag soup, results become unpredictable.

Comment: how to implement correctly?

Comment: for your given input it's working when you change `val(text)` to `text(text)`

Comment: Pick a font unit? What does `6` mean for you? 6 pixels? 6 points? 6 rem? 6 centimetres?